# XML - DTD , two elements same attributes

Tags: xml, dtd

Why the following code is not correct?
XMLspy finds an error at element employee

```
<!ELEMENT personnel (contractor*,employee*,partner*)+ >
<!ELEMENT contractor (info)>
<!ELEMENT employee(info)>
<!ATTLIST info lname CDATA #REQUIRED fname CDATA #REQUIRED hiredate CDATA #REQUIRED firedate CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a space after `employee`.

The `info` element is also not defined.

If what you are trying to do is get the attributes on `contractor` and `employee`, then this does it:

```
<!ELEMENT personnel (contractor*, employee*, partner*)+ >
<!ELEMENT contractor EMPTY>
<!ELEMENT employee EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST contractor lname CDATA #REQUIRED fname CDATA #REQUIRED hiredate CDATA #REQUIRED firedate CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST employee lname CDATA #REQUIRED fname CDATA #REQUIRED hiredate CDATA #REQUIRED firedate CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

This is valid per the DTD above:

```
<personnel>
  <employee lname="Foo" fname="Bar" firedate="1" hiredate="2"/>
  <contractor lname="Foo" fname="Bar" firedate="1" hiredate="2"/>
</personnel>
```

Or you can share the attributes declaration like this:

```
<!ENTITY % shared "lname CDATA #REQUIRED fname CDATA #REQUIRED hiredate CDATA #REQUIRED firedate CDATA #REQUIRED">
<!ELEMENT personnel (contractor*, employee*, partner*)+ >
<!ELEMENT contractor EMPTY>
<!ELEMENT employee EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST contractor %shared;>
<!ATTLIST employee %shared;>
```

This way if you need to change the list of attributes, it will change for both `contractor` and `employee`.

Comment: Element info, has no subelements or text, it only has the attributes. Could you please help me a bitmore with the space or give me a link to a tutorial?

Comment: @DanielHaley Thanks. I had to look it up to refresh my memory because it's been a decade since I've worked with DTDs. It's all Relax NG for me now, with some XML Schema here and there.